# In a commutative ring $R$, $I+J =R$ for every non-zero ideal $J$ with $J\ne I$. Can I conclude that $I$ is principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

In a commutative with unity ring $R$ there is an ideal $I$ for which $I+J=R$ for every non-zero ideal $J$ and $J$ is not equal to $I$. Then I know $I$ must be maximal, but can I conclude $I=Rt$ for a $t$ contained in $I$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $t \in I$, $t \neq 0$ (if such a $t$ does not exist, then $I = \{0\} = R \cdot 0$). You have either $I = Rt$ (then you are done) or you have $I \neq Rt$, in which case you get $I = I + Rt = R = R\cdot 1$.

Comment: But why I=I+Rt ?

Comment: @user470412 We have $Rt \subseteq I$, so $I \subseteq I + Rt \subseteq I + I = I$.